# Is it possible for an app to know when a contact was called or an email was sent?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I have a quick question. I am assuming that this is not possible but thought what the heck why not ask. I know it is possible to fetch contacts into an app but is it possible for an app to know when a contact was called?

So if the user adds the contact to the app is there a way for the app to know when that contact is used.

Comment: I'd say that would be a huge privacy invasion..

Comment: That's what I assumed. I was hoping that I would be able to know if  a call was successfully placed if the contact was accessed from the app. It was an idea I had about keeping in touch with friends on a more regular basis but guess I would have to approach from another angle if I want to continue. Thanks for the response.